# Special DNS for other accessing other cluster's deployment

Tags: kubernetes, networking

For accessing local deployment there is `service1.namespace1.svc.cluster.local` special internal domain name, how can we access other cluster's deployment internally if we have 2 cluster (eg. cluster1 and cluster2?) without have to exposing it to public?